# About dropdown list control in gridview using c#

Tags: c#, dropdownbox

Am using the below code to bind and show the dropdown list in grid view. But it always show the first item whether the database table have the second or third.

```
    private void BindData1()
    {
        DataSet7TableAdapters.sp_getall_trv_config_masterTableAdapter TA = new DataSet7TableAdapters.sp_getall_trv_config_masterTableAdapter();
        DataSet7.sp_getall_trv_config_masterDataTable DS = TA.GetData();
        if (DS.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView2.DataSource = DS;
            GridView2.DataBind();



            }
        }

protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            Control ctrl = e.Row.FindControl("DDL_STATUS_FT");
            if (ctrl != null)
            {
                DropDownList dd = ctrl as DropDownList;
                DataSet7TableAdapters.sp_getall_trv_masterTableAdapter TA = new DataSet7TableAdapters.sp_getall_trv_masterTableAdapter();
                DataSet7.sp_getall_trv_masterDataTable DS = TA.GetData();
                dd.DataTextField = "fld_TName";
                dd.DataValueField = "fld_id";
                dd.DataSource = DS;
                dd.DataBind();
            }

        }
}
```

Design Code:

```
  <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="100px" HeaderText="TYPE">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_STATUS" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Enabled="false" >
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_edit_STATUS" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_STATUS_FT" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to show the save data as a selected value. But now the first item show always in dropdownlist. Please help me to do this..

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
                    DropDownList dd = ctrl as DropDownList;
                    DataSet7TableAdapters.sp_getall_trv_masterTableAdapter TA = new DataSet7TableAdapters.sp_getall_trv_masterTableAdapter();
                    DataSet7.sp_getall_trv_masterDataTable DS = TA.GetData();
                    dd.DataTextField = "fld_TName";
                    dd.DataValueField = "fld_id";
                    dd.DataSource = DS;
                    dd.DataBind();
                    dd.SelectedValue= "";//Put your value here which needs to be selected
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are not setting back the `index/value` what you saved in the database so after every binding it will by **default** shows up the **first item**

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `'SelectedValue'` on your dropdownlist on clientside like

```
SelectedValue='<%# Eval("fieldname") %>'
```